# Solaris Services : offline status when application running fine

Tags: solaris

I don't know if my title is significant but I hope you can help me.

I'm using Solaris Services (on a SunOS 5.10 station) to start/stop/restart business applications. The services work fine but I've some kind of issue.

The applications can also be start/stop/restart manually by scripts, and some users still use those old scripts (and I can't change their way to work). So I have to face sometimes to a disabled or an offline service, but the application running fine...

It's a problem because I use my services to monitor the state of each application on each server with a GUI, which is wrong in this case.

So I wonder if we can catch the status of an application and define the service status with it. Or anything like this.

Tell me if I'm not clear.

Comment: `svc -xv <service>` should give you some info as to why.

Answer (score 0):

Put following to your script somewhere in beginning:

```
if [ -z $SMF_FRMI ]; then
    echo "Don't be nasty!!!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Offline status is cause SMF can't start service because it's already up. Best not to let users be a root, but setup role that control your service and made selected users part of that role.